# jsf 2.1 a4j:commandButton does not render result table @ViewScope

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, java-ee-6, ajax4jsf

I have a web application which uses a4j:commandButton like this:

```
<h:form>
<a4j:region id="search_form">
<a4j:commandButton render="ListOfPerson" action="personBean.search" value="search" execute="@form" status="ajaxStatus"/>
</a4j:region>
<a4j:outputPanel id="ListOfPerson" ajaxRendered="true">
  <rich:datatable>...</rich:datatable>
</a4j:outputPanel>
</form>
```

The bean ist annotated with @ManagedBean(faces package) and @ViewScope. When i change the scope to @SessionScope, everything works like expected. Any ideas?

I'm using the following imports:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
```

Comment: Check imports. It should be javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped (and annotation @ViewScoped not ViewScope)

Comment: I've updated the post, already using @ViewScoped from faces.bean

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i removed the a4j:region around the a4j:commandButton and it works.